# Django Context Processors without the rest of Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use Django templates as a standalone application and I'm having issues with `Engine.context_processors`

My main file is:

```
from django.template import Template, Context, Engine

template_content = """ -- HEADER ---
{{ var|star_wrap }}
{% fullpath "filename_123.txt" %}
{{ abc }}
 -- FOOTER ---"""

data = {'var': 'Ricardo'}

engine = Engine(
    debug=True,
    builtins=['filters'],
    context_processors=(
        'context_processors.my_context_processor'
    )
)    
template = Template(
    template_content,
    engine=engine,
)
context = Context(data)    
result = template.render(context)
```

In my `filters.py` I have:

```
from django import template

# --- Filters
register = template.Library()  # pylint: disable=C0103

@register.filter(name='star_wrap')
def star_wrap(value):
    return "** " + value + " **"

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def fullpath(context, arg):
    print(context)
    return "/tmp/"+str(arg)
```

And in the `context_processors.py` I have:

```
def my_context_processor(request):
    return {'abc': 'def'}
```

Basically the data in my `my_context_processor` is ignored... the `{{ abc }}` is not being substituted. See the output of the code above. I also print the context:

```
[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'var': 'Ricardo'}]
 -- HEADER ---
** Ricardo **
/tmp/filename_123.txt

 -- FOOTER ---
```

Any idea why the `my_context_processor` is being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Use `RequestContext` instead of `Context`...